# Collision detection: Shapes overlap even after using intersects method

Tags: java, swing, collision-detection

I am writing a code in which a circle moves randomly in a box and if it collides with any of the small rectangles inside it, it changes its heading direction/ bounces back. I am using the intersects method to find the collision between them. But the circle sometimes overlaps the rectangles rather than bouncing back on contact. I am bouncing back the ball by changing the orientation (180+current_orientation).

I am trying to solve this issue, but did not found any success yet. I read that intersects is finding the match by checking overlap of the bounding rectangles. But, how can I fix this issue. Is this problem due to the intersection or is there any issue with the way i am changing orientation. Any idea?

Code:

```
private void collisionAvoidanceRobot(int x, int y, int r, double robot_orientation2)
    {
        boolean collide1=false;
        boolean collide2=false;
        boolean collide3=false;
        boolean collide4=false;
        boolean collide5=false;
        boolean collide6=false;
        r+=5;
        Shape collisionrobot=new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,r,r);
        collide1=collisionrobot.intersects(obst1);
        if(collide1)
        {
            robot_orientation=180+robot_orientation;
        }
        collide2=collisionrobot.intersects(obst2);
        if(collide2)
        {
            robot_orientation=180+robot_orientation;
        }
        collide3=collisionrobot.intersects(obst3);
        if(collide3)
        {
            robot_orientation=180+robot_orientation;
        }
        collide4=collisionrobot.intersects(obst4);
        if(collide4)
        {
            robot_orientation=180+robot_orientation;
        }
        collide5=collisionrobot.intersects(obst5);
        if(collide5)
        {
            robot_orientation=180+robot_orientation;
        }
        collide6=collisionrobot.intersects(obst6);
        if(collide6)
        {
            robot_orientation=180+robot_orientation;
        }

    }

public void setXPosition_robot(int x)
    {
        double distance=0;
        distance = unit_moved + randomDouble(0, forwardNoise);
        robot_x= (int) (x + Math.sin(Math.toRadians(robot_orientation))*distance);
        //System.out.println("Robot_X:"+robot_x);
    }

public void setYPosition_robot(int y)
{
    double distance=0;
    distance = unit_moved + randomDouble(0, forwardNoise);
    robot_y=(int) (y+ Math.cos(Math.toRadians(robot_orientation))*distance);
    //System.out.println("Robot_Y:"+robot_y);
}

private void createRobot(Graphics2D g)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> robot_list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    robot_list=positionRobot(robot_x,robot_y);
    robot_x=robot_list.get(0);
    robot_y=robot_list.get(1);
    setNoise(0.05,0.05,5.0);
   //System.out.println("Robot:"+robot_x+"--"+robot_y+"--"+robot_orientation);
    adjustRobotOrientation();
    collisionAvoidanceRobot(robot_x,robot_y,robot_radius,robot_orientation);
    drawRobot(g,robot_x,robot_y,robot_radius);
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: If you could provide a screenshot, it'd probably help.

Comment: You might want to use a library for this: http://www.jbox2d.org/

Comment: @tieTYT attached screenshot.

Comment: @tieTYT Do you think the problem is with the intersects method?

Comment: Without a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve there are always guesses involved, but the "answer" by pseudonym might aim at the right issue: Depending on how the sequence of movement and collision tests is, it might notice a collision and turn around, but then **still* be in a colliding state and immediately turn around again. (In many cases, it is beneficial to *not* move when the *target* state would be a collision. Roughly like `Point newPos = computeNewPosition(); if (doesNotCollideAt(newPos)) { currentPos = newPos } else { /* Don't move there */ }`, but this has some caveats as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the circle appear to wobble? since you are moving the circle a random distance each iteration, the distance that it moved into the square could be greater than the distance it gets on the next iteration to move in the opposite direction, this would cause the circle to "stick".

also, your collisionAvoidanceRobot could use a for loop instead of all those ifs

Comment: Yes the circle wobbles and then slowly slowly overlaps the rectangle. I am not using random every time. I am just using random first time and then, i add the distance calculated by setters into it. How should I fix it then. Thanks, i will change that to a loop.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by only the first time? is setXPosition_robot not called every iteration? I can't tell as it's not called directly from anywhere in the represented code

Comment: anyways, you there are several ways to fix it, would could increase the speed for just the next iteration so that it always clears the rectangle, you could set a flag that makes it ignore intersections until it's clear (not suggested), or you could call a function that sets the x,y coords of the circle so that it's just clear of the rectangle based on it's orientation (probably the cleanest method)